# How to connect API to my project in WPF .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, wpf, api, .net-core-3.1

I have API with link

> https://webservice.sampleVPN.com/serverlist.php

and following is my model class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace VPN.Model
{
public class ServerModel
{
    public string error { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public Server[] servers { get; set; }
}

public class Server
{
    public string sid { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string dns { get; set; }
    public string port { get; set; }
    public string psk { get; set; }
    public string pptp { get; set; }
    public string l2tp { get; set; }
    public string tcp { get; set; }
    public string udp { get; set; }
    public string openconnect { get; set; }
    public string ikev2 { get; set; }
    public string sstp { get; set; }
    public string p2p { get; set; }
    public string videostreaming { get; set; }
    public string security { get; set; }
    public string voip { get; set; }
    public string enable { get; set; }
    public string maintmode { get; set; }
    public string iso { get; set; }
    public string free { get; set; }
    public string recent { get; set; }
    public string time { get; set; }
    public string fav { get; set; }
    public int Pingrate { get; set; }
    public string IsFavorite { get; set; }

    public string FavProtocol { get; set; }
}
}
```

I want to connect my API to the .Net project and store the data from api in a list so that it can be use later in the project later such as listview to select any server to connect VPN and showing country name,city, pingrate and more.

Comment: What have you tried so far...? You can call the web service using WebClient or RestSharp (third-party nuget package) and deserialize it in your object.

Comment: I am new to api, I understand the concept but I am unable to do the implementation of API so its not clear how to do things with APIs.

Comment: I have added an answer which works for me, but it is my preferred approach and other people may suggest alternatives.

Comment: When most people talk about `API`s these days they simply mean making HTTP calls, usually with JSON payloads. You can easily make HTTP GET and POST requests with the HttpClient class. To create or parse JSON you can use .NET Core's JsonSerializer class or JSON.NET

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have a listview I simply want to populate data from api to my listview in the project where there is dns which can be use as link to connect to vpn.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have uploaded a project on github for that if you would like to contribute to it there is the link for you. https://github.com/MHamzaJawed/Add-Data-to-List-view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are number of ways to achieve this, and this approach requires no additional dependencies.

obj will be the results deserialized into the ServerModel class.

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
 client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://webservice.casvpn.com/");
 HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("serverlist.php").Result; 
 if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
 {
      string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; 
      var obj = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ServerModel>(result);   
 }
```

To then bind these results to a ListView you can use the following code, however I think a DataGrid might be more suited to display multiple columns etc.

```
lvwServer.ItemsSource = obj.servers;
lvwServer.DisplayMemberPath = "dns"; //Or another property of Server you want to display
```

Comment: Those packages offer no benefit in this case - the same can be written using the built-in HttpClient and System.Text.Json, in as many lines. It will run faster too. If you want to propose using different packages, you have to explain what they offer

Comment: I appreciate that, which is why I said in my answer this was my preferred approach.

Comment: Preferred why? Why add extra dependencies and code? What do you gain by this? The answer isn't very helpful otherwise, especially for people that don't know the options or the tradeoffs

Comment: I agree and am all for reducing dependencies, and have updated my answer accordingly. Most of my work is done on large project that have multiple RestClients etc so I have a personal preference on RestSharp.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, moreover I have a window.xaml where there is a listview and I want to show all these 40 servers in that window. How can I achieve that.?

Comment: @RyanThomas I have uploaded a project on GitHub, would you like to contribute to it as well. the link to project is https://github.com/MHamzaJawed/Add-Data-to-List-view

Comment: I have updated my answer to display these in a listview.

Comment: @RyanThomas it is not allowing to bind the list view to that "obj"

Comment: You may need to make obj modular variable.